# Creating C++ DLL called from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm trying to find a tutorial on creating a C++ class in a DLL that can be called from C#. I've found a few tutorials but they either do not compile in VS 2013 Community or are not on point. The C++ object has only a few exported functions (i.e., that are called from the consuming C# app like ptr->StartAction()). It has about 70 procedures that are not exposed, in assembly language which is why I need to use C++. Currently I expose some functions in the DLL via dllimport etc. But C# requires using fixed(...) (to prevent garbage collection) which slows everything down quite a bit (and they are called 1,000,000s of times). Hence the need to move all that into the DLL. So I need a class that I can instantiate in the C# calling program and then call the public methods in the dll. I'm using .NET 4.0. The DLL will only be used by this one C# app.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it through the help of COM component and IDL with an output of Interoperability dll where you can use in your c# project. For more details follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DllImport` attribute of C#. Here is a sample signature:

```
[DllImport("path to dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
public static extern string methodName(string parameterName);
```

C# will call the method with the same name in the DLL.

Its impossible to say what you really need, because we don't have your method declarations.